# ansible conditional issues

Tags: linux, ansible

this playbook gets total RAM, and based on that sets two variables, say A & B
A is 40% of total RAM
B is 60% of total RAM

task is, if A greater than or equal to 32, then A must be 32, but if is less than 32, then keep A as is resulted from 40% of the total RAM
same goes with B, if B greater than or equal to 32, then B must be 32, but if is less than 32, then keep B as is resulted from 60% of the total RAM

```
- name: get total RAM
  set_fact:
    total_ram_mb: "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}"

- name: calculate min & max values
  set_fact:
    A: "{{ (total_ram_mb * 0.4 / 1024) | int }}"
    B: "{{ (total_ram_mb * 0.6 / 1024) | int }}"

- debug:
    var: A

- debug:
    var: B

- name: limit min value
  set_fact:
    A: "{{ 32 if A >= 32 else A }}"

- name: limit max value
  set_fact:
    B: "{{ 32 if B >= 32 else B }}"

- debug:
    var: A

- debug:
    var: B
```

but later tasks A B are always set to 32, no matter if A is greater, equal or less, memory on my vms are 8G
not sure where's issue

here's output of the play

```
[root@autom ansible]# ansible-playbook -i inv.txt memory.yml

PLAY [es] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1]
ok: [es2]

TASK [memory : get total RAM] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1]
ok: [es2]

TASK [memory : calculate min & max values] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1]
ok: [es2]

TASK [memory : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1] => {
    "A": "3"
}
ok: [es2] => {
    "A": "3"
}

TASK [memory : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1] => {
    "B": "4"
}
ok: [es2] => {
    "B": "4"
}

TASK [memory : limit min value] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1]
ok: [es2]

TASK [memory : limit max value] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1]
ok: [es2]

TASK [memory : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1] => {
    "A": "32"
}
ok: [es2] => {
    "A": "32"
}

TASK [memory : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [es1] => {
    "B": "32"
}
ok: [es2] => {
    "B": "32"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ansible are you running? If I try your playbook as written, it fails with this error:

```
TASK [limit min value] **********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ 32 if A >= 32 else A }}): '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"}
```

If I fix the task to perform explicit conversion to `int`, like this:

```
- name: limit min value
  set_fact:
    A: "{{ 32 if A|int >= 32 else A }}"

- name: limit max value
  set_fact:
    B: "{{ 32 if B|int >= 32 else B }}"
```

Then the playbook seems to work as intended. When `total_rm_mb` is `4192`:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "A": "1"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "B": "2"
}
```

And when it's `63993`:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "A": "24"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "B": "32"
}
```

This is with Ansible version 2.15.1.

Comment: ```ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27```

Comment: with ```| int``` trick it works